# @Override fix-code shortcut in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, overriding, shortcut

sorry for a silly question but I got angry after seeking the answer in NetBeans and in the net - is there any key shortcut for fixing @Override annotation in NetBeans (something like ctrl+shift+i for imports)?

I do appreciate your answers,

cheers.

Answer (score 3):

In netbeans **7.2** try `Refactor -> Inspect and Transform...`

then select the `Single Inspection` and the **"Add @Override annotation"**.

Then just follow the wizard.

Comment: This must have a shortcut!

Answer (score 0):

If you enable it as a hint, you will get a hint indicator and Alt-Enter will give you the option of adding the @Overrides.

To enable the hint, go to `Tools > Options > Editor > Hints > JDK 1.5 and Later > Add @Override annotation`